Prove that the differential map is surjective (by induction)
I am trying to prove the same theorem as in this post but using induction. I am aware of the other proof, but I think it is possible to show it by induction. Here is the question for reference: 
My problem is that I am stuck on the base case. Once I got it right, I think I can finish.
My approach (base case): Let $z \in R$. We must show that there exist a $p$ such that $Dp = z$. Let $e_1(x) = x$. Suppose that $De_1 = c$ (there must be such as $c$ from hypothesis on $D$). Problem here: now I want to construct $p(x) = \frac{z}{c}x$ to conclude, but I cannot, because nothing prevents $c = 0$ to be true...
I would be very grateful if someone had an idea of how to proceed further. Thanks in advance.

The $0$ polynomial does not have degree $0$. (Remember that the degree of a polynomial is the largest exponent of all the monomials appearing with nonzero coefficient.)
